# Populating XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, file, simplexml, populate

Currently, a friend of mine is wanting a Flash Gallery and the ability to upload files. I don't have the time of day to teach him where to edit the XML properly or dare I even give him FTP access.

He hand picked out this gallery program: http://flashnifties.com/xml_gallery.php Which as you can tell works off XML.

Creating a script to have him upload files to a directory is a non-issue. My issue is that what's the proper way to loop through a directory and populate an XML file.

A friend suggested the `PHP function SimpleXML` and I was wondering if anyone else had a similar solution.

Comment: simple xml is what you want. try it. use it. love it. Unless you wan to to build up your xml using `$str .= "<$element>$elementValue</$element>`. ug.

Comment: If you need more control over your XML and prefer [open standard APIs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/), you might want to look into [DOM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DirectoryIterator for looping through directory (possibly even RecursiveDirectoryIterator)
2. SimpleXML indeed to build (simple) XML